# Pass Windows Credentials to Smtp Client?

Tags: c#, smtp

Here is the code I have so far

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com");

 client.Port = 587;
 client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
 client.EnableSsl = true;
 client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

This didn't work.

I also tired

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

When I use debbuger both times the credentials are empty.

Comment: you need to pass in the network credentials like this I would think 
`client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("yourusername", "yourpassword");`

Comment: Is there a way to avoid hardcoding it in there? I was hoping to use the windows login credentials.

Comment: yes it would be passing parameters.. is this for a system account..? if so store the system username and password in a .config file and read it's values from there passing / replacing where you see "yourusername, yourpassword" with the actual string variables for user and password

Comment: if you want to pass user / password then you need to set the following to false 
`client.UseDefaultCredentials =false `

Comment: Credentials only work if there is a local email account for the current login on the PC where the program is working.  When outlook is run for the first time on a PC by a user outlook creates a local account for the user.  The CredentialCache uses the same credentials that outlook uses.